# How can I supply multiple conditions in spark startsWith() function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, startswith

I have a dataset with 5 Million records, I need to replace all the values in column using `startsWith()` supplying multiple or and conditions.

This code works for a single condition:

```
df2.withColumn("Deposits", when(col("Deposits").startsWith("0"),"1.1").otherwise(col("Deposits"))).show()
```

I need to do this:

```
df2.withColumn("Deposits", when(col("Deposits").startsWith("0"||"1"),"1.1").otherwise(col("Deposits")))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `rlike` with regex `^(1|0)` (starts with 1 or 0):

```
df2.withColumn(
  "Deposits",
  when(col("Deposits").rlike("^(1|0)"), "1.1").otherwise(col("Deposits"))
).show
```

If you want to update `Deposits` column depending on the startwith condition, you can chain multiple when expressions like this:

```
val depositsCol = Seq(
  ("1", "1.1"),
  ("2", "1.2")
).foldLeft(col("Deposits")) { case (acc, (start, value)) =>
  when(col("Deposits").startsWith(start), value).otherwise(acc)
}

df2.withColumn("Deposits", depositsCol).show
```

Answer (score 3):

You can separate the two conditions and combine them with `||` (or):

```
df2.withColumn(
    "Deposits",
    when(
        col("Deposits").startsWith("0") || col("Deposits").startsWith("1"),
        "1.1"
    ).otherwise(
        col("Deposits")
    )
)
```

Comment: This seems to not work how I expect when the column has a Null value.